# Template vs model

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

What is the difference between ***template*** and ***model*** in the context of ***programing*** and ***apps***.

Thanks all,

Comment: That depends on what programming language you're using - in some, **template** is a reserved word with a very specific meaning.  In others, it's not.

Answer (score 4):

A **template** is a pattern or mold: something you fill in to produce a finished product.

A **model** is a finished product similar to what you're looking to produce.

Comment: @user1975155: My pleasure.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation!  
Though I would say: A **model** is similar to the finished product one is trying to produce, but still not finished yet.

Comment: @Peter: That depends. Neither Hadrian's Pantheon, on which so many structures have been modeled, nor the prototypes of Mona Lisa and Madame X, were unfinished products. Cosmically speaking, that is.

Comment: Your examples are neither programs nor apps...:)
Is not a prototype, by definition, an **unfinished** product?

Comment: @Peter: I thought we were discussing things in general. In general, a prototype is more often than not a finished product. According to the standard definition of the word, which may or may not be in accordance with the prophecy. IT people and computer geeks are weird, you know. They'll call anything a prototype. Whoever came up with all that computer-related lingo cannot have been a well-read person. An app is an appetizer served before the meal. It also means an excessively lascivious mother-in-law in Portuguese, I think.